# The html script could not send the Complaint value of the form to the php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is the **HTML** code:- https://pastebin.com/Rc3AGC8x

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#ccccb3">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(min,max) {
        var x;
        x= Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        document.getElementById("complaint").value =x;
        //document.write(x);
    };
    </script>
<center>
<form action="http://localhost/PHPMailer-master/" method="post">
<p>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="n" placeholder="Name" name="n" required></p>
  <p>E-Mail: <input id="e" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="e" required></p>
  <p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea id="m" placeholder="write your message here" name="m" rows="10" required></textarea></p>
  <p><input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form" onClick="hello(112,78945)"></p>
  <input type="hidden" value="The complaint id is : #" id="complaint" name="complaint">
  <!--<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>-->

</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **PHP** code:- https://pastebin.com/g0Cnh8iR

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
    $n = $_POST['n'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
    $c = $_POST['complaint'];}
else{
$n='';
$e='';
$m='';
$c='245';
}
$mail->setFrom('noreply@gmail.com', 'Panasonic');
$mail->addAddress('testpanasoniccontact@gmail.com', 'Pragzz');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Complaint Number: '.$c;
$mail->Body    = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p><b>Message: </b>'.$m.'</p>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent. Your complaint will be attended within 48 hours. Your complaint No. is '.$c;
}
?>
```

**Password and username** field has been deliberately removed.

The HTML Script contains a form field of the hidden type with **Complaint as ID**.

It is not able to fetch the value from **javascript function** and send to the php code.

Comment: Your code has major security flaws; please read up on SQL Injection

Comment: Clicking on the button triggers form submission. You should not expect the browser to perform other scripting tasks in that situation. What’s the purpose of this anyway? If you just need a random value, you might as well create one in PHP directly ...

Comment: @Rushikumar: Where is the SQL injection vulnerability here?

Comment: @David accessing $_POST superglobal directly

Comment: @Rushikumar: It sounds like *you* might want to read up on SQL injection.  You don't seem to know what that term means.

Comment: @David I do stand corrected, as his PHP code does not interact with a database---accessing $_POST directly irked me, leading me to post that comment.

Comment: @Rushikumar: It's fairly common for web applications to receive values from a POST request and to use those values.  I don't know why this concept "irks you", but it's not an insecure or invalid concept at all.  It is, in fact, a *very standard* way to send data from a page back to the server.

Comment: @David, I understand that... and I also understand that it is all context dependent. I personally would want to validate and sanitize the data before doing anything with it; I do not trust the end user. Again, just personal preference, is all.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. I have modified the JS part and also placed the hidden feild before the submit button. It working good now.

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#ccccb3">
<center>
  <form action="http://localhost/PHPMailer-master/" method="post">
      <p>Name:<input id="n" placeholder="Name" name="n" required></p>

      <p>E-Mail: <input id="e" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="e" required></p>

      <p><textarea id="m" placeholder="write your message here" name="m" rows="10" required></textarea></p>

      <input type="hidden" value="100" id="complaint" name="complaint">

      <p><input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form" onClick="hello(112,78945)"></p>

  </form>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(min,max) {
      var complaint = document.getElementById("complaint").value
      console.log(complaint); 
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```